# add custom properties into inherited system.windows.forms.button

Tags: c#, button, properties

How to add custom properties into visual studio properties windows for inherited class from controls of system.windows.forms ?

example custombutton:

```
public class CustomBtn:Button
{
    public int MaxImgNumber{get;set;}
    public int MinImgNumber{get;set;}
}
```

I would like to show "MaxImgNumber" into the properties windows when i click on the custom buttons, like picture below
[image]

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`BrowsableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> Specifies whether a property or event should be displayed in a Properties window.

Comment: I believe you need to create CustomBtn as a User Control. Not just a class.

Answer (score 1):

Propertys that are marked with the `BrowsableAttribute` set to `true`, can be modified at design time:

```
public class CustomBtn:Button
{
    [Browsable(true)]
    public int MaxImgNumber{get;set;}
    public int MinImgNumber{get;set;}
}
```